# Print JSON and terminate execution for more detailed error reports

Tags: php, json, error-handling

I would like to know if there is any way to print a JSON in a die function like this:

```
die(json_encode($response));
```

Of course I've tested that and is not working as expected because it requires a string, I don't want to parse the JSON, I want to echo it as it is.

I have also thought about a custom function like:

```
public function reportError ($errorFlag, $message){
  $response = array($errorFlag, $message, $mysqli->error);
  echo json_encode($response);
  die ("");
}
```

But I'm not sure if it is a good way to do it or there is something more simple. I'm normally pretty worried about good practices but I'm lost with this issue.

Any guidance is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you need to `echo` inside the `die()` function. Like: `die(echo json_encode($response));`

Comment: @ImClarky I doubt it, I'm going to try it but die is a function which only accepts a string so that wouldn't make sense, I wrote the die just as an incorrect but intuitive example of what I want

Comment: Ah my mistake. I mixed up `echo` with `print_r`. `print_r` has an optional parameter to return value as a string; so something like this `die(print_r(json_encode($response), true));` should work.

Comment: @ImClarky It works perfectly thank you, go ahead and build an answer, this is what I'm using `die (print_r(reportError("Unable to connect to DB",$db),true))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print_r()` inside of your `die()`.

[**`print_r()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) has an optional second parameter, that if set to `true` returns the result as a string, rather than printing the result. So something like this should work:

```
die(print_r(json_encode($response), true));
```